# Can the battery in a Samsung 500T tablet PC be replaced?

Tags: battery

Can the battery in a Samsung 500T Tablet PC can be replaced by a user?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not possible for a "normal" user.

Also for future questions, I would recommend you to take the user-manual for example at [manualonline](http://www.manualsonline.com/).

Comment: It depends on the user.  but basically it's possible.

Comment: For example: iFixit can open/dismantle almost every device. So it is possible. But yes, I know, what you mean. But that's why I said "it's not possible for "normal" users".

Comment: iFixit can dismantle any device the question is can the device be put back together.  The answer in a case like this tablet is "no".

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I have edited my answer. I've tried to explain it a bit too "deep". :)